# jQuery slideDown() error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

When I set up my site like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <div id="leftStreak">
        <span class="inputLabel">E-mail:</span>
        <input name="login" id="loginInput" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div id="rightStreak">
        <span class="inputLabel">Password:</span>
        <input name="password" id="passwordInput" type="password"/>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-in" id="login"/>
</form>
<br />      
<p id="mainLabel">Something gone wrong... Contact with admin.</p>
```

CSS:

```
#mainLabel {
    width      : 300px;
    height     : 100px;
    font-size  : 200%;
    background : #A60000;
    text-align : center;
    position   : relative;
    border     : 2px dotted white;
    left       : calc( 50% - 150px );
    z-index    : 3;
    display    : none;
}
```

And I give animation `slideDown()` when it's sth wrong with login or password to `#mainLabel`, but when animation is done, background and borders stay at the same place except text.

I don't know what's going on, but it's depends on animations that I've done before. And when these previous animations are going, text from the "not animating right now things" is somehow moving.

That would mean that animations on higher elements would have influence on the lower elements. That doesn't make any sense! I've been researching for that issue, and google that, but I found nothing.

I run that both Chrome and Firefox, same issue.

Requesting help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

@ps2goat
Yea that snippet presents what I done. Except that these "#leftStreak, #rightStreak" are animating too, and when it's going that text in the "#mainLabel" is somehow moving. ONLY text, everything is in same place. So that is the rest:

JS:

```
$("#leftStreak").hide().delay(1300).slideDown(700);
$("#rightStreak").hide().delay(1400).slideDown(700);
$(".inputLabel").each( function() {
    $(this).hide().delay(2200).slideDown(500);
});
$("input").each( function() {
    $(this).hide().delay(2400).slideDown(500);
});
```

and then when sth wrong:

JS:

```
 $("#mainLabel").slideDown();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdHuP.png - link to the screenshot.

Comment: I don't see any attempts at javascript in your example.

Comment: Yea, I agree, but I think that one line of code is important. Point is in the text I wrote.

Comment: But I'm trying to create a snippet for you, and I want to see what you've tried.

Comment: Here it is: $("#mainLabel").slideDown();

Comment: That's why i said that before. ;)

Comment: That is *not* what your question said...  "And I give animation slideDown() when it's sth wrong with login or password to #mainLabel,"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this isn't what you're seeing, you'll have to give us more animation code to analyze or post an image. It seems to work for me.

```js
$('#mainLabel').slideDown();
```

```css
#mainLabel {
    width      : 300px;
    height     : 100px;
    font-size  : 200%;
    background : #A60000;
    text-align : center;
    position   : relative;
    border     : 2px dotted white;
    left       : calc( 50% - 150px );
    z-index    : 3;
    display    : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <div id="leftStreak">
        <span class="inputLabel">E-mail:</span>
        <input name="login" id="loginInput" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div id="rightStreak">
        <span class="inputLabel">Password:</span>
        <input name="password" id="passwordInput" type="password"/>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-in" id="login"/>
</form>
<br />      
<p id="mainLabel">Something gone wrong... Contact with admin.</p>
```

Comment: Just changing position relative to absolute repaired that.